How to get the last row added to a certain table
I use TypeORM with Nest.js in my backend and I need a method to get the last row added to a table in order to get its id (not auto incrementing). My goal is to use it for API call and I need the id + 1.
I tried nothing yet because I couldn't find a method in the TypeORM documentation that allows me to do what I want.

Why would you need the max id ? In most case, when you have a unique id represented by an integer, its automatically incremented when you add new data to a table.

await this.yourEntityRepository.findOne({
  order: {
    id: 'DESC',
 },
});


While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works? This can help future readers understand and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.

This code may work if the db never fails, but if the de db fails it will` generate a "secret and hidden" id that is not shown in the table. My goal is show those failed id row too
